# Not able to customize response data for my django serializer if many=true is passed as argument

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am not able to customize `response.data` for the serializer i am using if i am passing `many=True`.

Below is the serializer i am using to serializer my organization data.

**serializers.py**

```
class OrganizationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # fields

    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = ('name',)

    @property
    def data(self):
        request = self.context['request']
        href = request.build_absolute_uri()  
        ret = super(OrganizationSerializer, self).data        
        # Below i am customizing serializer data based on my specific
        #    requirement. 
        ret = {'href':href, 'items':ret}
        return ReturnDict(ret, serializer=self)
```

**views.py .**

```
# view code ---
organizations = Organization.objects.all()
response = OrganizationSerializer(organizations[0], context={'request':request})
return response.data
```

I am able to get `response.data` as `{'href': '<url>', 'items': {}]`
as per our code.

But when i am doing below -

```
organizations = Organization.objects.all()
serializer = OrganizationSerializer(organizations, many=True, context={'request':request})
```

I am not able to get response.data as `{'href': '<url>', 'items': {}]`.
I want that response with my response.data with or without using many=True.

I looked into source code of serializers.py(django rest app) and found that if many=true is passed as argument then ListSerializer will be used to return serialized data.

**Edit :**

**models.py**

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by overriding `many_init` method.

```
class OrganizationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # fields

    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = ('name',)

    @property
    def data(self):
        # come into action when.
        # response = OrganizationSerializer(organizations[0], context={'request':request})         
        request = self.context['request']
        href = request.build_absolute_uri()  
        ret = super(OrganizationSerializer, self).data        
        # Below i am customizing serializer data based on my specific
        #    requirement. 
        ret = {'href':href, 'items':ret}
        return ReturnDict(ret, serializer=self)

    @classmethod
    def many_init(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # come into action when 
        #response = OrganizationSerializer(organizations, many=True, context={'request':request})
        res = super(OrganizationSerializer, cls).many_init(*args, **kwargs)            
        request = kwargs['context']['request']
        href = request.build_absolute_uri()                   
        res.items = {'href': href, 'items': res.data}
        return res
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **SerializerMethodField** to format your data then the **Meta** class to specify what fields to return, so based on your snippet logic the solution should look as follow:

```
    class OrganizationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        href = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        items = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

        class Meta:
            model = Users
            fields = ('href', 'items')

        def get_href(self, obj):
            request = self.context['request']
            return request.build_absolute_uri()

        def get_items(self, obj):
            data_list = User.objects.filter(id=obj.id).values()
            return data_list[0]
```

Check [SerializerMethodField Doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

Comment: Did you run that  ? it is giving : RuntimeError
Exception Value: 
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object .